# How do I split multiline cells into arrays for Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I keep a spreadsheet of the titles and issue numbers I've read for various comics. I want to have a column that provides the count of the issues read for each title. Some titles have issue numbers in multiple lines. For example, the run of Avengers starting in 2016 has the following issue numbers listed in one cell, each range on a new line within the cell:

```
#1-11
#1.1-5.1
#1MU
#672-676
```

I tried to write a script that would separate each line into an array item, and then for each item in the array, extract the numbers using regular expressions to perform calculations to determine the total count. (The count of the above issues is 22, but the problem is getting the script to determine that for me and for the other titles as I update issue numbers.)

Here's what I have so far:

```
function calcIssueCount(x) {
  // Set initial value to 0:
  var issueCount = 0;
  // Make an array from the lines of the cell
  // split by the line break:
  var box = x.split("\n");
  for (var line in box) {
    // Determine if the line includes a 
    // range of issue numbers, indicated
    // by presence of a hyphen:
    if ("-" in line === True) {
      // Remove the # symbol from the string:
      line = line.replace("#","");
      // Extract the number before the hyphen
      // and delete the hyphen:
      var a = line(/[0-9}+\.|[0-9]+-/);
      a = a.replace("-","");
      // Extract the number after the hyphen 
      // and delete the hyphen:
      var b = line(/-[0-9}+\.|[0-9]+/);
      b = b.replace("-","");
      // Turn a and b into numbers:
      a = number(a)
      b = number(b)
      // Subtract the range start from the 
      // range end:
      var c = b - a;
      // Add 1 because a range of 1-5 includes 5
      // issues, while 5-1 is only 4:
      c += 1;
      // Update the count for the number of 
      // issues in the cell by adding the 
      // line's value:
      issueCount += c;
    }
    else {
      // If there's no hyphen, there's no 
      // range; the count of issues on the
      // line is 1:
      issueCount += 1;
    }
}
}
```

`calcIssueCount(x)` would have x as the cell name (e.g., D15).

I'm likely making mistakes all over the place, but I especially think I'm not understanding something about getting the cell data into the array into the first place. What am I missing here?

Comment: Here's a inbuilt formula method: `=-SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(IMREAL(TO_TEXT(SPLIT(B34,"#"&CHAR(10)))&"i")+IMAGINARY(TO_TEXT(SPLIT(B34,"#"&CHAR(10)))&"i"))-1)`

Comment: @I'-'I I could study from your comment. Thank you so much. How about posting your comment as an answer? Because I thought that your answer is also useful for OP and other users.

Comment: Oh this looks cool. Of course, I can understand less of it than the Javascript. I guess I have something to study, just as Tanaike says! So thanks! This method has just one problem, though: it creates a lot of negative values. If I only read issue #207 of a series, for example, the issue count ends up as -206. Any book with only one issue in a series is counted as 0, etc. Would absolute values somewhere fix this? Or rather some way of adding a fake value to subtract from? I guess tomorrow I'll take a look into what inferror, imreal, to_text, and imaginary do in spreadsheet formulas.

Comment: @Tanaike & thektulu7 Thanks, But this is better left as a comment. When checked on OP's sheet, It fails on multiple levels. Script solution is much easier and adaptable. If I manage to find a better solution, I'll post an answer. Thanks again.

Comment: @I'-'I Thank you for your reply. I understand it. But I could study from your comment. Thank you for about this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to retrieve "22" from the following value in a cell.

```
#1-11
#1.1-5.1
#1MU
#672-676
```

As the logic for retrieving "22" from the value, I understood as follows.

- Retrieve `1` and `11` from `#1-11`.
- Retrieve `1.1` and `5.1` from `#1.1-5.1`.
- Retrieve `672` and `676` from `#672-676`.
- Subtract before number from after number for each line.
- Add 1 to all lines.
- For the line without `-`, add only 1.

From above logic, `(11 - 1 + 1) + (5.1 - 1.1 + 1) + (1) + (676 - 672 + 1) = 22` can be obtained. If my understanding of your logic is correct, how about the modification like below?

#### Modification points :

- When `for (var line in box) {` is used, each element can be retrieved by `box[line]`.

  - In this modicication, I used `forEach`.
- In Javascript, the boolean express "true" and "false".
- `Line` is not an object. So `"-" in line` occurs an error.

  - In this modification, I used `indexOf()`.
- In Javascript, `number()` is `Number()`.
- When you want to use `calcIssueCount(x)` as a custom function, in your current script, no values are returned. So if you want to retrieve `issueCount`, please add `return issueCount`.
- I couldn't understand about the function of `line(/[0-9}+\.|[0-9]+-/)`. I'm sorry for this.

In my modification, I retrieved both the before and after numbers using a regex of `([0-9.]+)-([0-9.]+)`. I think that there are several solutions for your situation. So please think of this as one of them.

#### Modified script :

Pattern 1 :

In this pattern, your script was modified.

```
function calcIssueCount(x) {
  // Set initial value to 0:
  var issueCount = 0;
  // Make an array from the lines of the cell
  // split by the line break:
  var box = x.split("\n");
  box.forEach(function(e){
    if (e.indexOf("-") > -1) {
      var numbers = e.match(/([0-9.]+)-([0-9.]+)/);
      // Extract the number before the hyphen
      // and delete the hyphen:
      var a = Number(numbers[1]);
      // Extract the number after the hyphen 
      // and delete the hyphen:
      var b = Number(numbers[2]);
      // Subtract the range start from the 
      // range end:
      var c = b - a;
      // Add 1 because a range of 1-5 includes 5
      // issues, while 5-1 is only 4:
      c += 1;
      // Update the count for the number of 
      // issues in the cell by adding the 
      // line's value:
      issueCount += c;
    } else {
      // If there's no hyphen, there's no 
      // range; the count of issues on the
      // line is 1:
      issueCount += 1;
    }
  });
  return issueCount;
}
```

Pattern 2 :

This is other sample script. In this pattern, the regex is not used. The result is the same with pattern 1.

```
function calcIssueCount(x) {
  return x.split("\n").reduce(function(c, e) {
    if (e.indexOf("-") > -1) {
      var numbers = e.slice(1).split("-");
      c += (Number(numbers[1]) - Number(numbers[0])) + 1;
    } else {
      c += 1;
    }
    return c;
  }, 0);
}
```

#### Result :

[image]

#### Note :

- In this modified script, the regex of `([0-9.]+)-([0-9.]+)` is used for the sample value. If you want to use values with other patterns, please tell me. At that time, can you show me more samples?

#### References :

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [String.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)
- [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)
- [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: No this is wonderful. I feel so dumb for forgetting the return function. I haven't done coding for awhile, and it was with Python before this. Thanks for the explanations of better/correct JavaScript in the modifications section of your answer. There's no other pattern. I chose this cell because it features all of the variations of numbering patterns. Thanks so much!

Comment: When I try to use these improved scripts, I get the following error: TypeError: cannot use instanceof on a non-object (line 5). I've tried reading about instanceof to see if I can work out a fix but I fail to see the connection.

Comment: @thektulu7 I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. Can you provide the sample spreadsheet? If you can do, I can confirm the situation using your sample sheet. If you cannot do, feel free to tell me.

Comment: Here's a copy of it: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UWpVbUwyMS1kGQXVwBjvj7ihPYY48gZ6FV8qKdJMvj8/edit?usp=sharing I appreciate your help. I'm trying to understand this stuff but I haven't coded anything in a while. Afraid I've gone rusty what little I learned a few years ago...

Comment: @thektulu7 I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. And thank you for sharing the sample sheet. I confirmed that the script works. So please try as follows. 1. Rename ``function calcIssueCount(x) {`` in the project of ``Copy of IssueCount`` to ``function calcIssueCount_org(x) {`` just in case. And save it. 2. For example, put ``=calcIssueCount(D7)`` to "E7". If this didn't work, please tell me.

Comment: HA! It worked! Now I know to be careful about names among copies of the scripts. Dunno why I didn't think of it. Now I see that there is one type of numbering I didn't consider, but I think I can manage to alter the algorithm to factor it in. Thanks again!

Comment: DONE! Some issues were numbered, for example, 1.1-1.5 instead of 1.1-5.1, as most decimal point issues were. So I had to add a conditional check for cases where `b - a < 1` and multiply the `b` and `a` by 10 before subtracting. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @thektulu7 I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.